# How to run a Java program from mac terminal?

Tags: java, macos

I've downloaded the source code for Java program ([Mario AI Benchmark](http://code.google.com/p/marioai/downloads/list)) that I'd like to work with to eventually integrate some Python scripts. No matter what .java file I try running I get the same error:

```
alavin$ java src/ch/idsia/scenarios/Play.java
Error: Could not find or load main class src.ch.idsia.scenarios.Play.java
```

Is there something I need to do after downloading the source code before I can run any .java files? I.e. do I need to compile, unpack, make anything?

I'm relatively new to Java and appreciate any help you can offer.
I've gone through some Java tutorials but they're too simple -- i.e. I'm still unsure how to run a large Java program with a multiple directories (res, src, etc.)

UPDATE:
I have tried to first compile with `javac src/ch/idsia/scenarios/Play.java` and the compiling step returns 15 errors, all similar to `ch/idsia/scenarios/Play.java:3: error: package ch.idsia.ai.agents does not exist`.

Do I need to compile all the directories at once? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: did you read the getting started instruction https://code.google.com/p/marioai/wiki/GettingStarted ?

Comment: @XavierCombelle yes but still had a bunch of issues with CLASSPATH. I decided to run the API via Eclipse instead and all is well :)

Answer (score 2):

First you need to compile the program to a `.class` file using `javac`.

```
javac src/ch/idsia/scenarios/Play.java
```

Then execute the `.class` file created (Note - Without the `.java` or `.class` extension)

```
java src/ch/idsia/scenarios/Play
```

Ref - [Documentation on Compiling](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/compile-136656.html)

> **Compiling the Program**
>
> A program has to be converted to a form the Java VM can understand so
>   any computer with a Java VM can interpret and run the program.
>   Compiling a Java program means taking the programmer-readable text in
>   your program file (also called source code) and converting it to
>   bytecodes, which are platform-independent instructions for the Java
>   VM.

Comment: *I'm relatively new to Java* ---- Same here, but this is common sense!

Comment: Great answer... Which is easily found on Google ;)

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai The first link, after searching it on google!!! :) Now I am thinking why he has tagged [python]!

Comment: Please see the question update above.

Comment: @alavin89 Please do not update your question after you get an answer. There are 2 reasons as to why 1) Many people will not get to see the update as the majority if the traffic will have skipped it after there is an answer. (As you can see I waited for 24 hours after your comment there has been only 23 views) 2. It will invalidate the answer. The right thing to do is either put the whole question at once, or ask a new one. At present I suggest you to remove your update from the question and ask a new question. However note that you will need to accept this as an answer before you do so. Thanks